# How to convert a string to clicable URL in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have URL column for each record in pandas DataFrame.

```
Name             CRMLinks                             NamedLink
Clint Eastwood   HTTP://example.com/link1/100e1e         Clint
Iron Side        HTTP://example.com/link2/202e1e         Iron
```

I want to convert `CRMLinks` and `NamedLink` column to clickable links to get to the URL that is shown in CRMLinks.

Here is what I have

```
base_url= 'https://example.com/'

df['CRM'] = base_url + df['CRM']

def make_clickable(link):
    # target _blank to open new window
    # extract clickable text to display for your link
    text = link.split('=')[1]
    return f'<a target="_blank" href="{link}">{text}</a>'

# link is the column with hyperlinks

df['CRM'] = df['CRM'].apply(make_clickable)
```

But I only get this in the df['CRM'] cell.

```
<a target="_blank" href="HTTP://example.com/link1">100e1e</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use:

```
df.style.format({'CRM': make_clickable})
```

This will make those clickable

---

```
base_url= 'https://example.com/'

df['CRM'] = base_url + df['NamedLink']

def make_clickable(link):
    print(link)
    # target _blank to open new window
    # extract clickable text to display for your link
    text = link.split('=')[0]
    return f'<a target="_blank" href="{link}">{text}</a>'

# link is the column with hyperlinks
df.style.format({'CRM': make_clickable})
```

---

```
    Name            CRMLinks                         NamedLink  CRM
0   Clint_Eastwood  HTTP://example.com/link1/100e1e  Clint  https://example.com/Clint
1   Iron_Side       HTTP://example.com/link2/202e1e  Iron   https://example.com/Iron
```

Comment: If I do that I :
df['CRM'] = df.style.format({'CRM': make_clickable})

now get this in each row
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f9db25015f8>

Comment: Check my answer. Updated one

Comment: ok now I get the clean URL in jupyter notebook. Should that not clickable? Am I wrong in expecting that the link should be clickable in jupyter notebook. This is what I get now in the dataframe: HTTP://example.com/link1/100e1e

Comment: It will be clickable only since I have used `style.format`

Comment: But it is not clickable since when I click on the link in the data frame within Jupiter notebook, it does nothing. Are you testing it in jupyter notebook

Comment: Yes In jupyter notebook only.

Comment: I can copy and paste it in the browser and it works, but not clickable directly within the dataframe on jupyter notebook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216979/discussion-between-stryker-and-pygirl).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this line is the error. Replace your line :

```
return f'<a target="_blank" href="{link}">{text}</a>'
```

TO this n try:

```
return f'<a target="_blank" href="{link}/{text}">{text}</a>'
```

Comment: I get the same target blank....
<a target="_blank" href="HTTP://example.com/link1">100e1e</a>.  Please note the base_url in my code. That may help